# how to schedule a cron job to run every second week

Tags: cron

I have a cron command which I using currenly for run daily. I want to make it run every second week Monday morning 9AM. please advice

```
0 0 * * *  curl -s -L web.url.com/user/adminNotifier
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this site to generate Cron command

```
http://crontab-generator.org/
```

hope this helps you